# Calculation of the average memory access time based on the hit rate and hit times?

Tags: caching, computer-science, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I find it hard to calculate the average time for a memory access and would just like to give an example of a problem that I have tried to solve. I would appreciate if someone could tell me if I'm on the right track, or if I'm wrong what I have missed.

Consider the following multilevel cache hierarchy with their hit times and hit rates:

- L1-cache, 3 cycles, 50%
- L2-cache, 5 cycles, 90%
- Main memory, 70 cycles, 100%

Now I think:

AMAT (Average Memory Access Time) = Hit time + Miss rate * Miss penalty

= 3 + 0.5 * (15 + 0.3 * 70) = 21 cycles

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: It depends if the L2 hit time is *total* time for an L2 hit, or additional time after an L1 miss.  Costing only an extra 2 cycles is plausible if L2 is probed in parallel with L1.  But if it's supposed to be a total of 8 cycles for an L2 hit, that requires assuming that time to detect an L1 miss is the same as L1 hit time.  (Which is normal; usually an L1 cache will fetch tags and data in parallel so data is ready in the same cycle as you detect hit or miss.)  But it's still somewhat ambiguous, unless there's some established convention your book / course uses.

Comment: Where does your "200" come from?  A 39-cycle AMAT is way too high when ~95% of accesses hit in fast L1 or L2, only 5% having to wait for 70-cycle main memory.

Comment: Sorry I edited it.

Comment: @PeterCordes This is the full question. Therefore Idk how to calculate it

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is correct, however the values you've plugged in are a bit off.

AMAT = HitRate_l1 + MissRate_l1*(Miss Penalty L1)

Now, Miss Penalty of L1 = HitRate_l2 + MissRate_l2*(Miss Penalty L2) and finally,

Miss Penalty L2 = 70 cycles since we've been given that the main memory has a 100 % hit rate.

Therefore the final calculation comes out as 3 + 0.5(5 + 0.1(100)) = 10.5 cycles.